# How to wait for all Timer Tasks to be done?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I've got multiple `System.Threading.Timer` which starts in parallel. In the end, I have got a `Task.Wait` to wait till all tasks are done. But it doesn't wait for all, how can I make it wait for all?

```
private List<Task> todayTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var item in todayReport)
{
    todayTasks.Add(SetupTimer(item.Exec_Time, item.Report_Id));            
}

Task.WaitAll(todayTasks.ToArray());
```

--SetupTimer--

```
private Task SetupTimer(DateTime alertTime, int id)
{
    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime.TimeOfDay - current.TimeOfDay;

    if (timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero) {
        //TODO: ERROR time already passed
    }

    ExecCustomReportService executeCustom = new ExecCustomReportService();

    return Task.Run(
        () => new Timer(
            x => executeCustom.AdhockReport(id), null, timeToGo, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Why do you use timers and not simple `Task`s?

Comment: The `Action` given to `Task.Run` simply constructs the `Timer` object. So as soon as the `Timer` is constructed, the task completes.

Comment: @YacoubMassad That's pretty much is an answer to the question.

Comment: when did you intend to start the timers ?=!

Comment: Do you know that `ExecCustomReportService` is thread-safe?

Comment: It would be really great if you posted valid code. You've declared `todayTask` and then you go ahead and use it as `todayTasks`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @YacoubMassad stated in the comment, your task is merely creating the timer and returns.

What you could do is get rid of the timer and use `Task.Delay`:

```
return Task.Delay(timeToGo).ContinueWith(t=> executeCustom.AdhockReport(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really better off using a tool that is suited to the job. I'd suggest Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx). Then you can do this:

```
var query =
    from item in todayReport.ToObservable()
    from report in Observable.Start(() => executeCustom.AdhockReport(item.Report_Id))
    select report;

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(
            report =>
            {
                /* Do something with each report */
            },
            () =>
            {
                /* Do something when finished */
            });
```

You just need to NuGet "System.Reactive".